# Create an array with on click events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

So I have a set of check boxes that are created dynamically with the following code:

```
<?php foreach($candies as $candy): ?>

     <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="candy list-group-item" data-id="<?php echo $candy['candy_id']; ?>" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-content="<img src='<?php echo $candy['candy_img']; ?>'>"><?php echo $candy['candy_name']; ?></a>

     <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $candy['candy_id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $candy['candy_name']; ?>" style="display:none;" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This results in the following (shortened) code:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="candy list-group-item" data-id="1" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-content="&lt;img src='http://www.groovycandies.com/pc/catalog/8992_General.jpg'&gt;" data-original-title="" title="">Raspberry Gummi Bears</a>

    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Raspberry Gummi Bears" style="display:none;">


    <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="candy list-group-item" data-id="2" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-content="&lt;img src='http://www.groovycandies.com/pc/catalog/candy-runts-5.jpg'&gt;" data-original-title="" title="">Runts</a>

    <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Runts" style="display:none;">

    ...
</ul>
```

And then I have javascript that when the `<a>` above is clicked the correct `checkbox` is either checked or unchecked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(".candy").click(function(){

        var id = $(this).data('id');

        var checkbox = $("#"+id).prop("checked");

        if ( checkbox != true) {

            $("#"+id).prop("checked", true);

            $(this).attr("class","candy list-group-item active");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#"+id).prop("checked", false);

            $(this).attr("class","candy list-group-item");
        }

    });

    </script>
```

Now I'm to the point of submitting the form... but before I do so, I want to do one more thing. Which I can't figure out.

I want to make an array in php which I understand is: `<?php $candies = array(); ?>` and that will create a blank array. Now when a check box is checked I want to add the name of the check box to the array. Or when the check box is unchecked it is removed from the array. I want this to happen before the form is submitted. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use same name for name attribute for every checkbox. <input type="checkbox" name="candy[]"/>. then u can access this checkbox values as $candy=$_POST['candy']. this variable is an array and will contain only the checkbox values which has been checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be done without a link, and javascript, you can do it with just a label like this:

Make the checkboxes an array, by noting the input `name` attribute. The additional `[]` sends an array to the server.

```
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="Raspberry Gummi Bears" /> Raspberry Gummi Bears</label></p>
<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="candies[]" value="Runts" /> Runts</label></p>
```

Then on the PHP Side:

```
<?php
$candies = $_POST["candies"];
print_r($candies);
```

Comment: It doesn't make the preferred appearance, also it was not the question.